# Using IEX API for real-time stock info (Yahoo Finance replacement)?

Tags: excel, api, stockquotes, elixir-iex, vba

Just like the title says, I'm looking for a replacement source for stock info now that Yahoo has disabled the API many people have been using. The new source I've been looking at is found here: https://iextrading.com/developer/

My question is how to actually get the data in to Excel...I was thinking through VBA since that is what I had used to get the data from Yahoo. However, I think what I would like to do is well beyond my current abilities...I also tried using Excel's WEBSERVICE() function with the following URL to simply look at a price: https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/price but that didn't work. From my understanding, IEX has made a plethora of data available to us for free, I just don't know how to access it. My reasoning for VBA is so that I am able to use an input list from a workbook for tickers, and would be able to put this data access in many workbooks. Any help is much appreciated. Additionally, any sort of direction as to where I can look to begin learning this on my own would be similarly welcome. Thanks.

Update: Code mentioned in my comment

```
Function StockPrice(ticker As String, item As String) As Double

Dim strURL As String, strCSV As Double, itemFound As Integer, tag As String

itemFound = 0
If item = "lastprice" Then
    tag = "price"
    itemFound = 1
ElseIf item = "pe" Then
    tag = "peRatio"
    itemFound = 1

End If

If itemFound = 1 Then

    strURL = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" & ticker & "/" & tag
    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
    XMLHTTP.send
    StockPrice = XMLHTTP.responseText
    Set XMLHTTP = Nothing

Else

    StockPrice = "Item Not Found"

End If

End Function
```

Comment: Update: Tried the following code (in the question section because it is too long for a comment) and it works for price, but not P/E Ratio or any other parameter besides "quote". Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've mostly solved the issue. Here is the code for anyone who is interested. This works as a direct replacement for those using Yahoo Finance's API.

```
Function StockPrice(ticker As String, item As String)

Dim strURL As String, strCSV As Double, itemFound As Integer, tag As String

itemFound = 0
If item = "lastprice" Then
    tag = "latestPrice"
    itemFound = 1

ElseIf item = "pe" Then
    tag = "peRatio"
    itemFound = 1

ElseIf item = "company" Then
    tag = "companyName"
    itemFound = 1

ElseIf item = "sector" Then
    tag = "sector"
    itemFound = 1

ElseIf item = "open" Then
    tag = "open"
    itemFound = 1

ElseIf item = "yclose" Then
    tag = "previousClose"
    itemFound = 1

ElseIf item = "change" Then
    tag = "change"
    itemFound = 1

ElseIf item = "%change" Then
    tag = "changePercent"
    itemFound = 1

ElseIf item = "marketcap" Then
    tag = "marketCap"
    itemFound = 1

ElseIf item = "52high" Then
    tag = "week52High"
    itemFound = 1

ElseIf item = "52low" Then
    tag = "week52Low"
    itemFound = 1

End If

If itemFound = 1 Then

    strURL = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" & ticker & "/quote/" & tag
    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
    XMLHTTP.send
    StockPrice = XMLHTTP.responseText
    Set XMLHTTP = Nothing

Else

    StockPrice = "Item Not Found"

End If

End Function
```

IEX has much more functionality than I've built here. Just not experienced enough to build around it. Check those features here: https://iextrading.com/developer/docs/

Comment: Hey thanks for this... it solved my problem. I also found this JSON documenting every function, it's parameters and responses: https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/

Answer (score 3):

This maybe a bit simplistic, but it's a start:

```
Sub IEX()
Dim Price As Single

    Price = Application.WebService("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/price")

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm only able to test the webservice functionality as a standard function using Excel online as the computer I'm on currently is running Excel 2010. If I went this route, it doesn't seem too difficult to convert to a workbook function that I could then use to reference a ticker in a cell. However, I would lean towards staying away from the webservice idea, only so that the functionality remains through different versions of Excel. I appreciate your response! I may end up using your suggestion in the interim as it does appear to be on the track to my goal.

Answer (score 2):

With ticker symbol in one cell (cell E3 in this example), enter the following in another cell:

```
=WEBSERVICE("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" & E3 & "/quote/delayedPrice")
```

Works in Excel for Office 365.

Comment: Your answer is poorly worded. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: @sparkplug, I completely understood the wording of this post. Upvoting because it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need backwards compatibility with Yahoo, and just want a simple price quote, this VBA function adds a quote capability to the list of Excel functions.

It's not polished, but should serve as a simple example of how to use the powerful IEX API.  Use the VBA editor to put this in a module:

```
Public Function tickerPrice(ticker As String)

Dim htmlCmd As String
Dim curlCmd As String
Dim shellCmd As String
Dim sResult As String

htmlCmd = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" & ticker & "/quote/delayedPrice"
curlCmd = "curl \""" & htmlCmd & "\"""
shellCmd = "do shell script "" " & curlCmd & " "" "

sResult = MacScript(shellCmd)

tickerPrice = Val(sResult)

End Function
```

Be sure to enable Macros when opening the workbook, so this can function.  (This was tested with Mac Excel 2011, with High Sierra, in 2017.